# Fractional-Order Moments

Tags: moment-of-inertia, moment

Commonly seen in physics(and statistics) are the concepts of moments of order zero(mass), one(center of mass), and two(moment of inertia). In statistics a third moment (referred to as skewness) also exists and is used. Actually, mathematically the moment can (of order n) be simplified to an operation in the form of:

[image]

Once I look at this equation it begs the question: what if n is a ratio. What could be some physical applications of this fractional-order moment?

Comment: Fractal physics and phase transitions.

Comment: by phase transitions can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: You could take a peek at critical exponents: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_exponent. Near critical points, where systems undergo phase transitions, they exhibit a complex behavior that can be described by non-integer power laws as their scaling functions.